# Are there any html aware wysiwyg editors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, wysiwym

I'm looking for a Wysiwyg editor where I can insert html tags as well as classes and id's for the tags? I'm looking for something that will allow someone to actually change the html of a site rather than simply a rich text editor that converts to simple markup, I've been looking for a good hour or so but can't find anything, does anyone know anything like that?

requirements:

- able to insert tags
- able to nest tags
- able to apply class to tags
- able to apply id to tags

if anyone has anything remotely similar to this let me know (Even if it's not ruby, I'm interested regardless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE is a great option.  Check it out.

http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: Yeah, I'd looked at this as well as a few other options, they don't offer the ability to add classes and ids to tags as I'd like but I guess I'll try extending them with jquery. Thanks Matt.

Comment: @MikeH-R: no need to extend it, there are a bunch of plugins that do that already.

Comment: Are there? I just had a glance around and can't seem to find anything that fits the bill, could you point me in the right direction?